# Why does {terra} r library not have a mean method for the project function?

Tags: raster, r, terra

Why when using the terra::project function, is there no 'mean' or 'max' or 'min' etc method for how one raster is projected to another resolution and alignment?

https://rdrr.io/github/rspatial/terra/man/project.html

From the documentation:

```
character. Method used for estimating the new cell values of a SpatRaster. One of:

near: nearest neighbor. This method is fast, and it can be the preferred method if the cell values represent classes. It is not a good choice for continuous values. This is used by default if the first layer of x is categorical.

bilinear: bilinear interpolation. This is the default if the first layer of x is numeric (not categorical).

cubic: cubic interpolation.

cubicspline: cubic spline interpolation.
```

Given these are relatively simple compared to the above methods, this feels like a deliberate choice.

Answer (score 3):

The aim of a reprojection is to produce a grid on the new projection that accurately represents the values of the source grid on the new grid.

Interpolation methods like bilinear, cubic, etc try to do that by assuming a smoothness of the surface and guessing what the value at a projected grid cell might be.

Doing something like a "max" or "mean" would be putting a processing step on top of a projection step. For one, you'd have to specify the spatial range of the mean or max, and that's not really pertinent to a coordinate reprojection. If you want to do some sort of focal max or mean then its probably best done with inputs and outputs on the same coordinate basis.

Comment: That makes sense but what is an alternative way to do this? I have two rasters with the same crs: high resolution r1 and lower resolution r2. I want a new raster r3 with the same origin and resolution as r2 where each cell is the mean of all r1 cells that fall in that cell.

Comment: That's an aggregate operation, its not a projection, so this Q is irrelevant. If the high res is a simple division of the low res then `aggregate`, otherwise you have to consider fractional overlaps etc and you should ask this as a new question if you want to know.