# Preserving RGB values with projectRaster in R

Tags: raster, coordinate-system, r

I'm using R and trying to change the CRS of a GeoTIFF (loaded as RasterStack) with RGB bands to a different CRS. To do this, I'm using projectRaster(). The issue I have is that it seems that the RGB values are being transformed too. Depending on the source and target CRS the RGB values can even become negative.

Here's an example:

```
library(raster)

# download sample GeoTIFF
download.file("https://github.com/EOxServer/autotest/raw/f8d9f4bde6686abbda09c711d4bf5239f5378aa9/autotest/data/meris/mosaic_MER_FRS_1P_RGB_reduced/mosaic_ENVISAT-MER_FRS_1PNPDE20060816_090929_000001972050_00222_23322_0058_RGB_reduced.tif", "sample.tif")

geotiff <- stack("sample.tif")

print(geotiff)
```

The output of that last command is the following (note the values of the three bands are in the range 0-255)

```
class      : RasterStack 
dimensions : 449, 541, 242909, 3  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution : 0.031355, 0.031355  (x, y)
extent     : 11.33175, 28.29481, 32.19025, 46.26864  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
names      : sample.1, sample.2, sample.3 
min values :        0,        0,        0 
max values :      255,      255,      255
```

Now, when I do the projection

```
geotiff_proj <- projectRaster(geotiff, crs = CRS("+proj=utm +zone=15 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs"))
print(geotiff_proj)
```

The output of the last command shows that the range of the RGB values has changed after the projection

```
class      : RasterBrick 
dimensions : 916, 744, 681504, 3  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution : 4140, 3220  (x, y)
extent     : 4813823, 7893983, 11461710, 14411230  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=utm +zone=15 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs 
source     : memory
names      : sample.1, sample.2, sample.3 
min values :        0,        0,        0 
max values : 252.7174, 253.5180, 253.4433
```

Is there a way to change the coordinate system of the raster without affecting the RGB values?

Comment: I do not know R but the source image is a 8-bit RGB image and if you do not change the data type of the image then max values `252.7174, 253.5180, 253.4433` are impossible because 8-bit values can only be integers on range 0-255. I wonder what they present.

Comment: @user30184 R is storing them as floating point decimal numbers. They'll get rounded to integers for colour plotting. They are still under 255 which is all that matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The transformation has to choose new RGB values for the cells in the transformed coordinate system grid. By default it uses a "bilinear" interpolation that smooths things a bit. I'm not sure how this can create values outside the range of the data (like your report of negative values, not reproduced here) unless possible some extrapolation might be doing it. Not sure.

The alternative method is "nearest neighbour". This is usually used for categorical data. Suppose 1=sea and 2=trees and 3=desert. A pixel that is half on trees and half in desert when recomputed via a transformation will get a value of 2.5 by interpolation, which is meaningless, so categorical data uses "nearest neighbour" which will always pick one value from the source grid cells for each destination grid cell.

If you do this for your RGB raster then you should get a raster which only has colours that are present in the source raster. This doesn't look much different to doing it by the default method. One of these is bilinear interpolation, the other is nearest neighbour. I'm not sure which is which:

[image]

```
geotiff_proj2 <- projectRaster(geotiff, 
    crs = CRS("+proj=utm +zone=15 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs"), 
     method="ngb")
```

You could also investigate the differences between these two rasters.

Comment: This worked. Thanks! I can't make available the example that resulted in negative values, but with your solution it works fine and keeps the range 0-255.

Answer (score 1):

`terra` recognizes RGB coded rasters, and in version 1-5-20 (currently the development version, you can install it with `install.packages('terra', repos='https://rspatial.r-universe.dev')`) it uses nearest neighbor as the default method for such a raster. So all you need to do is:

```
download.file("https://github.com/EOxServer/autotest/raw/f8d9f4bde6686abbda09c711d4bf5239f5378aa9/autotest/data/meris/mosaic_MER_FRS_1P_RGB_reduced/mosaic_ENVISAT-MER_FRS_1PNPDE20060816_090929_000001972050_00222_23322_0058_RGB_reduced.tif", "sample.tif")

library(terra)
x <- rast("sample.tif")
p <- project(x, "+proj=utm +zone=33")

plot(p)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`terra` recognizes RGB coded rasters, and in version 1-5-20 (currently the development version, you can install it with `install.packages('terra', repos='https://rspatial.r-universe.dev')`) it used nearest neighbor as the default method for such rasters. So all you need to do is:

```
download.file("https://github.com/EOxServer/autotest/raw/f8d9f4bde6686abbda09c711d4bf5239f5378aa9/autotest/data/meris/mosaic_MER_FRS_1P_RGB_reduced/mosaic_ENVISAT-MER_FRS_1PNPDE20060816_090929_000001972050_00222_23322_0058_RGB_reduced.tif", "sample.tif")

library(terra)
x <- rast("sample.tif")
p <- project(x, "+proj=utm +zone=33")

plot(p)
```

With earlier versions you can do

```
p <- project(x, "+proj=utm +zone=33", method="near")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Projecting a raster is not the same than projecting a vector. While the points of the vector can be projected back and forth easily, projecting a raster implies transferring the value from one grid to a new grid on the desired CRS (see [Why does {terra} r library not have a mean method for the project function?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/421601/why-does-terra-r-library-not-have-a-mean-method-for-the-project-function)). So it is normal that values would change from one raster to another. That is the reason why `projectRaster` has a `method` argument, that specifies how the values on the new grid are computed from the initial grid.

You can find a better explanation here: https://geocompr.robinlovelace.net/reproj-geo-data.html#reproj-ras

Comment: Thanks for the second link, very informative. Although your answer didn't directly solve my issue, it helped me see that I probably want to do a "transformation" instead of a reprojection, or use vectors. Thanks